# Node-RED on Bluemix: Where are the flows?

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

Normally, Node-RED flows are stored somewhere in the filesystem, in a file named flows_XXX.json.

When running Node-RED on Bluemix where are they stored?
This could be important if your node instance doesn't start anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by Harald in a previous answer once you create an instance of nodered boilerplate it is bound to a cloudant nosql instance for data, instead of the classic json file: this because a file on the filesystem would be reset as soon as your application restarts, while a db service persists. 
So if you wish to retrieve your application flows once it isn't able to start anymore, you have to access the cloudant nosql dashboard and extract the data locally.

Answer (score 4):

A Node-RED instance on Bluemix when created from the Node-RED boilerplate always comes with a Cloudant database service connected.

1. Open the Cloudant dashboard
2. Open the database `nodered`
3. Open the document `<app_name>/flow` (Use the edit icon to open it)
4. You can now copy all the flows from this Node-RED instance.
   Simply remove this part from the beginning:

`{
"_id": "HUe-IoT-RED/flow",
"_rev": "6-3813d11089aa3e3adb9e704d4251bcdd",
"flow":`

and the tailing `}`

Everything between the `[ ]` are the flows. They can be imported into another Node-RED instance.

More info on [Node-RED website](http://nodered.org/) and [Node-RED GitHub repo](https://github.com/node-red/node-red)

Comment: I deleted my answer. Could you also add a link to the Node-RED website and their github repo? There is additional information.

Answer (score 2):

For the boilerplate install all data including flows is persisted to the bound cloudant database.

Details can be found in the node-red-bluemix repo - https://github.com/node-red/node-red-bluemix

Answer (score 1):

Generally when the node-red instance doesn't start anymore (if something is changed, etc.), you can 're-push' the starter - code on your old bugged application. So, the app is 'resetted' as the first time, but you don't lose the flows, cause they are stored in a Cloudant DB.

Comment: That won't fix things if the problem is caused by something in the flow, as re-pushing the app will not update the flow in the Cloudant DB.

Comment: of course, this 'workaroud' is fine only if the issue is related to nodejs (for example when the package.json import a module not more supported in Bluemix and node instance doesn't start anymore)